# how i can enable only one button onclick and disable all other using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an application that selects values from a button let me show you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKTki.png)

whenever we want to click one button disable all other buttons except that I choose, I don't understand how to achieve it.

here is code simplification:
https://github.com/mehditaib03/Tip-/blob/main/src/Components/Billinput.jsx

for the chunk code and concept consider this:
https://scrimba.com/scrim/c4LEQwf9

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
export function OtherMethod () {
 
  
    const [current,setCurrent]= useState(true)
  
    function myFunc(e){
        //loop overr each node of button
        //setcurrent node to false 
        //setOther node to true   
        console.log(e.target.disabled)
           
      }
      
   
  return (
      <div id="container" >
          <button id="1" disabled={current} onClick={myFunc}> click me</button>
          <button id="2" disabled={current} onClick={myFunc}>abc</button>
          <button id="3" disabled={current} onClick={myFunc} >def</button>
          <button id="4" disabled={current} onClick={myFunc}>ghi</button>
      </div>   
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `current` a boolean, make it `string | null`. Then, set `current` to the id of the button element in the `handleClick` function. I created a new `Button` component to encapsulate the logic. But the key here is the `disabled={current && current !== id}`, which which disable all of the buttons except the one that was last clicked.

```
const Button = ({ children, current, id, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button id={id} disabled={current && current !== id} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export function OtherMethod () { 
    const [current,setCurrent]= useState<string | null>(null);
  
    const handleClick = e => {
       setCurrent(e.target.id);
    }
    
  return (
      <div id="container" >
          <Button id="1" current={current} onClick={handleClick}> click me</button>
          <Button id="2" current={current} onClick={handleClick}>abc</button>
          <Button id="3" current={current} onClick={handleClick} >def</button>
          <Button id="4" current={current} onClick={handleClick}>ghi</button>
      </div>   
  )
}
```

Comment: yes looking good I think this approach will help me.

Comment: Consider upvoting and marked as the correct answer if this was helpful :)